# jQuery - Append element after next factor of 5

Tags: jquery, append

https://jsfiddle.net/f25sbwvL/

I have a list of items, grouped by 5 items per row. What I'd like to do is when you click one item it appends

```
<li class="expand"></li>
```

element to next factor of 5.

So when I click 1st item, it will append after 5, same with 2, 3, 4, 5. But when I click 6th item it should append after 10 item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add jquery lib and use following code:

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $(".items li").on("click", function(){
      $(".expand").remove();
      var index = $(".items li").index(this);
      var targetIndex = (Math.floor(index/5)*5) + 4;
      $('<li class="expand">Test</li>').insertAfter(".items li:eq("+ targetIndex +")");
  });
 });
}(jQuery));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/deLm3kq1/

Comment: Thank you so much!. Exactly what I needed.